# SQL union all to create a unified metrics view

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good day,

I've been working with the idea of creating a simple view "ViewMetrics", combining many tables into one predefined view for lookup on dashboards.

```
Select Date, Month, 'Sale' as Metric, Total as Value, NULL as Tags From SalesLedger

UNION ALL

Select Date, Month, 'Purchase' as Metric, Total as Value, NULL as Tags From Purchases
```

**Use Case:**

```
Select SUM(Value) as Sales from ViewMetrics where Metric = 'Sale' 
Group By Month
order By Month
```

or

```
Select SUM(Value) as Sales from ViewMetrics where Metric = 'Sale' OR Metric = 'Purchase'
Group By Date, Tags
```

I'm worried that with many union all statements in a growing database the view will select unnecessary data and kill performance.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: "Many" how many?

Comment: Clearly you know the potential issue that may arise, what testing have you done to determine the impact on your approach? Have you build a view around N tables and tested it? If so what was the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm worried that with many `union all` statements in a growing database the view will select unnecessary data

You need to keep an eye on execution plans but the SQL Server optimiser is capable of simplifying this and optimizing out unneeded references.

The rule `SELonUNIA` can push the filter down to the `UNION ALL` and redundant branches detected in the simplification phase and removed in the simplified tree.

```
CREATE TABLE SalesLedger(Date Date, Month int, Total int);

CREATE TABLE Purchases(Date Date, Month int, Total int);

go

CREATE VIEW ViewMetrics
AS
SELECT Date, Month, 'Sale' as Metric, Total as Value, NULL as Tags From SalesLedger
UNION ALL
SELECT Date, Month, 'Purchase' as Metric, Total as Value, NULL as Tags From Purchases


go

SELECT SUM(Value) AS Sales
FROM   ViewMetrics
WHERE  Metric = 'Sale'
GROUP  BY Month
ORDER  BY Month
```

In the above case the branch of the `UNION ALL` where the string constant 'Purchase' is being projected as the `Metric` column is removed during simplification as the `WHERE  Metric = 'Sale'` predicate would contradict this and the final plan only accesses `SalesLedger`

[image]

If the query is parameterised the plan gets a bit murkier

```
DECLARE @Metric VARCHAR(10) = 'Sale' ;

Select SUM(Value) as Sales 
from ViewMetrics 
where Metric = @Metric
Group By Month
order By Month
```

The plan references both tables

[image]

The filters have [startup expression predicates](https://sqlserverfast.com/epr/filter/#startup) so the tables underneath aren't actually accessed unless the `@Metric` is the one relevant to that table.

But still this might make cardinality estimates less accurate (as SQL Server doesn't know what table if any will be accessed) or the more general plan may have have other issues compared to a more specific one so you could consider adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to these queries to get them compiled as though passing the literal values.

Comment: Weirdly it seems to need an unnecessary `Sort` in the case of `group by date` without a `where`, even if both tables are indexed by `date`. You can manually do two-level grouping and get a `Merge Concatenation` but it won't do it for you https://dbfiddle.uk/NtzUlUSs Presumably a missing optimization associated with [Partitioned Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#partitioned-views)

Comment: @Charlieface - Not an ideal solution but adding `Total` as a key column gives you a merge concat https://dbfiddle.uk/ruTCp13D - certainly adds fuel to the "You need to keep an eye on execution plans"

Comment: @Charlieface  Also doesn't help that the tables are empty. If it thinks they are a bit larger it does a local/global aggregate https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ravwg.png - so each branch gets aggregated independently using index order and then it combines the partial aggregate from each branch - albeit though still with a sort

Comment: Whoops - Above image missed the `UPDATE STATISTICS`  statements https://i.stack.imgur.com/lptn3.png

Comment: Thank you. I do believe this addresses the issue I was concerned about and will be suited for my use-case as I can make due without parameterized queries.